# Recording desktop and webcam using MPlayer and save the result into file

Tags: 16.04, mplayer

I used [MPlayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/man/en/mplayer.1.html) to record the desktop and webcam on the same time.

```
mplayer tv:// -tv driver=v4l2:width=400:height=300 -vo xv -geometry 100%:100% -noborder
```

([credit](https://leehblue.com/record-screen-and-webcam-ubuntu/))

How to save the result into a file?